# Problem reading requestparam in controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

The request params are shown in the network but the second param (fileId) is received as null in the controller. The request returns 400 bad request.

```
@PostMapping(path = "/uploadFile")
public ResponseEntity<ServiceResponse> upload(
        @RequestParam(value = "id") Long userId,
        @RequestParam(value = "fileId") Long fileId,
        @RequestPart(value = "file") MultipartFile... file) {

    // 
        return ResponseEntity.ok(serviceResponse);
}
```

request URL: (the file is sent in the body: formData)
    http://localhost:8080/api/upload?id=9999&fileId=101

Comment: Do you also send a `fileId` key in your form-data? i.e. does the `file` parameter contain a `fileId` key? Because your `fileId` RequestParam should not be `null` with the request you provided, unless a `fileId` key is also part of the MultipartFile.

Comment: @Chaimae Aklibous There are a couple or reasons that could happen in Spring-MVC your controller has to have fileID in Model class to know it can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Well, could you show your request or the URL atleast?

Comment: I did add it now !

Comment: Why does your request use `api/upload` when you mapped your method to `api/uploadFile`?

Comment: api is defined in the project. Actually when required is set to false for fileId, things work fine. It receives the value of id but not fileId.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL should be 
`http://localhost:8080/api/uploadFile?id=9999&fileId=101`
instead of `http://localhost:8080/api/upload?id=9999&fileId=101`
because you have mentioned path as uploadFile